# asp.net Dropdownlist Customvalidator servervalidate referencing control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, detailsview, customvalidator

I have a dropdownlist that I populate from the DB, and depending on business logic I need to be able to validate the selected item (TEXT) from the dropdownlist with server side vaildation. Requirements state I cannot simply filter it out as part of the SQL statement. The solution I have been trying to get to work is to simply create a customvalidation in the code behind.

The validation is called, BUT I cannot figure out how to reference the ddl DataTextField value for the item selected. When I try and do the server side code below the asp.net system states that my dropdownlist does not exist within the detailsview and provides a red underline as a result. In this instance it will always be insertmode.

Suggestions

---

ASP Code

---

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtlSample" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateRows="false">
      <Fields>
```

.
.
.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Age") %>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPosition" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                LDataSource="Select Position, PositionId from ...." DataTextField="Position" DataValueField="PositionId"
                 ></asp:DropDownList>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPosition" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                LDataSource="Select Position, PositionId from ...." DataTextField="Position" DataValueField="PositionId"
                 ></asp:DropDownList>
          </InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvPos" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "DDLPosition"
          OnServerValidate="ddlPos_Check" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="My error message"></asp:CustomValidator>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Fields>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void ddlPos_Check(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
```

{

```
    if (ddPosition.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("some value")            
        args.IsValid = false;         
    else           
        args.IsValid = true;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Murphy's law, answer your own question a few hours after.

```
        DropDownList ddlList=DetailsView2.FindControl("ddlPosition") as DropDownList;

        if (ddlList != null)
        {

            if (ddlList.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("text")) {
                        args.IsValid = false;    
            }
             else
            {
                   args.IsValid = true;
            }

        }
```